# Looping and concatenating based on a condition in R

Tags: r, loops, string-concatenation

I'm new to R and still struggling with loops.

I'm trying to create a loop where, based on a condition (variable_4 == 1), it will concatenate the content of variable_5, separated by comma.

```r
data1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(123:127),
  agent_1 = c('James', 'Lucas','Yousef', 'Kyle', 'Marisa'),
  agent_2 = c('Sophie', 'Danielle', 'Noah', 'Alex', 'Marcus'),
  agent_3 = c('Justine', 'Adrienne', 'Olivia', 'Janice', 'Josephine'),
  Flag_1 = c(1,0,1,0,1),
  Flag_2 = c(0,1,0,0,1),
  Flag_3 = c(1,0,1,0,1)
)

data1$new_var<- ""

    for(i in 2:10){

      variable_4 <- paste0("flag_", i)
      variable_5 <- paste0("agent_", i)

      data1 <- data1 %>%
        mutate(!! new_var = case_when(variable_4 == 1,paste(new_var, variable_5, sep=",")))
    }
```

I've created new_var in a previous step because the code was giving me an error that the variable was not found. Ideally, the loop will accumulate the contents of variable_5, only if variable_4 is equal 1 and the result would be big string, separate by comma.

[image]

The loop will paste in the new var only the name of the agents which the flags are = 1. If Flag_1=1, then paste the name of the agent in the new_var, if not, ignore. If flag_2 =1, then concatenate the name of the agent in the new var, separating by comma, if not, then ignore...

Comment: I think you need to be clearer on what the condition is you are trying to test. Are you trying to test when the iteration value i == 1 then create the concatenation in new_var, because variable_4 will always be of the type "flag_1", "flag_2" etc - it will not be a number on its own like 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Your question will be a lot clearer if you create some example data (`data1` is not given) and your desired output you are trying to get

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if my questions wasn't clear enough. I have one variable that is called agent. Let say the content of the variable is agent_1, agent_2, agent_3, agent_4...agent_10. Let say that the flag (variable 4 ) is equal 1 only for agent_1, agent_4, agent_7. The loop would save in the new_var the content of agent variable, like new_var ="agent_1,agent_4, agent_7" for that row. The other agents would not be added, since the flag is not 1. Does it make sense?

Comment: I added a picture, I hope this helps?

Comment: Yes, the picture makes your expected output clear now. I'll edit to add data for `data1` to make your example reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a loop for this. The data is in `wide` format which makes it harder, but if we convert to `long` format, we can easily find a vectorized solution rather than using a loop.

The `pivot_longer` function is useful here which requires `tidyr` version >= 1.0.0.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

pivot_longer(data1, 
             cols = -ID, 
             names_to = c(".value", "group"),
             names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_var = paste0(agent[Flag==1], collapse = ',')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("group"),
              values_from = c('agent', 'Flag'),
              names_sep = '_') %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(ID, starts_with('agent'), starts_with('Flag'), new_var)

## A tibble: 5 x 8
#     ID agent_1 agent_2  agent_3   Flag_1 Flag_2 Flag_3 new_var                
#  <int> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>                  
#1   123 James   Sophie   Justine   1      0      1      James,Justine          
#2   124 Lucas   Danielle Adrienne  0      1      0      Danielle               
#3   125 Yousef  Noah     Olivia    1      0      1      Yousef,Olivia          
#4   126 Kyle    Alex     Janice    0      0      0      ""                     
#5   127 Marisa  Marcus   Josephine 1      1      1      Marisa,Marcus,Josephine
```

**Details:**

`pivot_longer` puts our data into a more natural format where each row represents one observation of the variables agent and flag, rather than several:

```r
pivot_longer(data1, 
             cols = -ID, 
             names_to = c(".value", "group"),
             names_sep = "_")

## A tibble: 15 x 4
#      ID group agent     Flag 
#   <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>
# 1   123 1     James     1    
# 2   123 2     Sophie    0    
# 3   123 3     Justine   1    
# 4   124 1     Lucas     0    
# 5   124 2     Danielle  1    
# 6   124 3     Adrienne  0 
# ...
```

For each ID, we can then paste together the agents which have flag values of 1. This is easy now that our variables are contained in single columns.

Lastly, we revert back to the `wide` format with `pivot_wider`. We also ungroup the data we previously grouped, and re-order the columns to the desired format.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you very much for your reply. I guess I dont have the tidyr version necessary because I'm getting the error of not finding the function pivot longer. I have agent_1: agent_10, would this solution work with more then 3 variables?

Comment: @DanielleTravassos yes, just install the latest `tidyr` version with `install.packages('tidyr')`. As long as your only columns are `agent_i` and `Flag_i`, this will work. If you also have other columns you will have to change the `cols` specification in `pivot_longer`

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any suggestions of other function I could used, since I can't change the version of R I'm working with?

Comment: @DanielleTravassos What R version are you on?

Comment: I'm on 3.5.1.  Thank you

Comment: `tidyr 1.0.0` can be installed on R version `3.1` or higher. What goes wrong when you install the latest `tidyr` and run the code in the answer?

Comment: I do have tidyr installed, but when I run the code i get the error "could not find function "pivot_longer". This might be because I dont have the latest version of tidyr?

Comment: did you run `install.packages('tidyr')` to make sure you have the most up to date version?

Comment: Hi Chris, I was talking to a co-worker and I can't install any new packages unfortunately but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this in BaseR or the tidyverse, or a combination of both, if you stick to using tidyverse then consider this:

I have used mtcars as your dataframe instead!

```
#load dplyr or tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# create data as mtcars
df <- mtcars

# create two new columns flag and agent as rownumbers
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(flag = paste0("flag", row_number())) %>% 
  mutate(agent = paste0("agent", row_number()))

# using case when in mutate statement
df2 <- df %>%  
  mutate(new_column = ifelse(flag == "flag1", yes = paste0(agent, " this is a new variable"), no = flag))

print(df2)
```

an ifelse statement might be more appropriate if you have one case - but if you have many then use `case_when` instead.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. It does work, but only once, because it's not looping.

Comment: yes - this is a convenient way of not using for loops - you can use a loop if you want, but your question was more of a data wrangling exercise so I thought it would be easier to  just use the tidyverse/dplyr instead. If you are happy with the answer please accept it by clicking the green tick mark thanks!